# Insert Foreign key into Table according to its Primary Key

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I am trying to to split a table into two table and want to add the reference (foreign key) of one table to another

For Example lets say there are is a table called customer table and an Column in it called Group Name has repetitive data which goes against data normalization, so I want to split the table on that column, which would be to replace that Group name Column with GroupID column

NOW form a new table with 2 column GroupID and Group Name and insert distinct Group values into GroupName column, with an auto-incrementing GroupID which will be the Primary key in the group table, and be refrenced in Customer table to act as a foreign key

Now the main question is how to Insert those Autoincremented GroupID of 'GROUP TABLE' into groupID of the customer Table or how do You Insert Foreign Keys into Customer Table According to the Main table

[image]

The customerTable With GroupID and  customerTable With Customer_Group are two diffrent table

```
UPDATE ch03.customerd 
JOIN ch03.group gr ON customer.Customer_Group = gr.Group_Name 
SET customerd.Group_ID = gr.Group_id
WHERE customerd.Customer_id = customer.Customer_id;
```

---

```
update ch03.customerd set Group_ID =
(select gr.Group_id
from ch03.customer as co
join ch03.group as gr on co.Customer_Group = gr.Group_Name)
where customerd.Customer_id = customer.Customer_id;
```

this is what i have tried and isn't working

Comment: "replace that Group name Column with GroupID column" is not normalization. Find out what normalization (to a "1NF" or to higher NFs) is. "isn't working" isn't helpful. For code questions give a [mre]. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. [ask]  [Use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all data except `group_id` is already transferred then

```
UPDATE new_customer_table nc
  JOIN old_customer_table oc ON nc.customer_id = oc.customer_id
  JOIN new_group_table ng ON oc.customer_group = ng.group_name
SET nc.group_id = ng.group_id
```

If new tables are empty yet then

```
INSERT INTO new_group_table (group_name)
SELECT DISTINCT customer_group 
FROM old_customer_table;

INSERT INTO new_customer_table (customer_id, .. , customer_age, group_id)
SELECT oc.customer_id, .. , oc.customer_age, ng.group_id
FROM old_customer_table oc
JOIN new_group_table ng ON oc.customer_group = ng.group_name;
```

PS. If `customer_group` in old table is not defined as ENUM / have no CHECK constraint which checks entered values for validity then I recommend to execute `INSERT INTO new_group_table ..` firstly and check the values inserted carefully. If some misprintings will be found then you need to edit source data before, then truncate `new_group_table` and repeat - until all group names are correct.